# Does a C# compiler optimize programs by default?

Tags: c#

I have two "Hello World" programs:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
  Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
}
```

and

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
  string hw = "Hello World";
  Console.WriteLine(hw);
}
```

and the IL code produced for each of these is:

```
IL_0001:  ldstr       "Hello World"
IL_0006:  call        System.Console.WriteLine
```

and

```
IL_0001:  ldstr       "Hello World"
IL_0006:  stloc.0     // hw
IL_0007:  ldloc.0     // hw
IL_0008:  call        System.Console.WriteLine
```

My question is, why did not, the C# compiler optimize this **by default**?

Comment: Do you have the optimization flags on?

Comment: @KevinHikaruEvans nope, running it on LinqPad actually, I was hoping if C# compiler would do something about it by default!

Comment: The second IL is common for debug output. Also, the JIT is likely to eliminate that if the program is not being debugged.

Comment: I don't understand why people downvote a question when a person is trying to learn something :-(

Comment: @Aniket I have to agree with you. People do it because they are afraid of people with passion to learn. They are afraid if they don't try and stop someone from learning then they will lose the edge.

Comment: [Required reading on c# compiler optimizations](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/11/what-does-the-optimize-switch-do.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# compiler optimizes for `Release` build. `Debug` build are not optimized!

**Optimized  [Release Build]**

```
.method private hidebysig static void Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
    .entrypoint
    .maxstack 1
    .locals init (
        [0] string hw)
    L_0000: ldstr "Hello World"
    L_0005: stloc.0 
    L_0006: ldloc.0 
    L_0007: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
    L_000c: ret 
}
```

**Non Optimized [Debug Build]**

```
.method private hidebysig static void Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
    .entrypoint
    .maxstack 1
    .locals init (
        [0] string hw)
    L_0000: nop 
    L_0001: ldstr "Hello World"
    L_0006: stloc.0 
    L_0007: ldloc.0 
    L_0008: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
    L_000d: nop 
    L_000e: ret 
}
```